# Unclear on the meaning/usage of "withPixiApp" for React Pixi

Tags: reactjs, class, pixi.js

I'm looking into React Pixi for a project, and I'm looking through the documentation. I came across [this](https://codepen.io/inlet/pen/RMLJKm) codepen project showcasing multiple moving objects in a single canvas. However, I am unfamiliar with this style of declaration in react:

```
 const Mover = withPixiApp(class extends React.Component {
```

I'm used to simply writing "class myClass extends React.Component," but this appears to be something new. Can anyone explain what this line is declaring for me, and how it differs from just saying "class myClass extends React.Component"?

Comment: HOC wrapping - like redux connect

Answer (score 1):

Someone answered my question that it's a Higher Order Component. I'll include the [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) to the react documentation in case anyone comes along later with a similar question and finds this post.